# How to allow different keyspaces to use different partitioners in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, partitioner

I am new to Cassandra and have a basic question regarding its partitioners.

According to the [Cassandra document](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/webhelp/index.html#cassandra/architecture/architecturePartitionerAbout_c.html#concept_ds_dwv_npf_fk), the partitioner of a cluster should be set in the cassandra.yaml file.  My question is: does this mean all keyspaces in a Cassandra cluster must use the same partitioner? If it's not, how to allow different keyspaces to use different partitioners?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All keyspaces must use the same partitioner.  This is to avoid requiring excessive configuration for each keyspace.  However, you can choose replication options per keyspace: whether you want multiple datacenter replication and replication factors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I don't get the "This is to avoid requiring excessive configuration for each keyspace." part.  I think it is fine to have a default partitioner set in the config file, and allow each keyspace to overwrite the setting.  Does Cassandra offer this?

Comment: No, the partitioner cannot be overridden per keyspace.  It would require setting tokens for each keyspace and would make a lot of operations more complex.  Also, you are very strongly encouraged to use the default (Murmur3Partitioner in 1.2.x) for everything.

Comment: I know that one is recommended, but I would like some of my column-families to be partitioned by the `ByteOrderedPartitioner`, which orders the key.  Or is it a bad idea?

Comment: It means you have to do manual balancing regularly. You also can't use virtual nodes.

Comment: Yes, but there are some cases that are required to process data in some order, so in this case is the Murmur3 still the king?

Comment: Murmur3 is still a hash based partitioner, so you can't do ordered range queries on rows. Instead you should use wide rows and range queries on columns.

Comment: What he means is, "take advantage of clustering [ordering] within a partition." :)